# jshint: funky code vs semicolons; how to silence all of jshint's complaints about semicolons here?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I'm not a fan of ASI.  But given that this is perfectly legit JavaScript, where exactly is it here that jshint (repeatedly, 8 times over) is expecting to find a semicolon?

```
    script.addEventListener('load', function () {
        ++i !== requires.length ? loader(i) : (loadLocal(thirdParty), loadLocal(main))
    }, true);
```

Comment: Holy unreadable mess, Batman! Please, please, please … just use an `if/else`

Comment: The end of the statement in the function? It's probably also confused by the comma expression, but not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end of your ternary expression.

i.e.

```
(loadLocal(thirdParty), loadLocal(main));
                                        ^ here
```

Comment: doh!  Should have seen that :P